# TextView setTextColor is not working on some android devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am using following code to change color of Text.This code works fine on some android devices but for Samsung Note 2 it is not working .

```
TextView number=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
number.setText("✔");
number.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tickcolor));
```

i have also tried android color class to change color but that also not worked

Comment: are you saying that, for example,  `number.setTextColor(Color.RED)` doesn't work?

Comment: I assume it's a special character .That's why have problem

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya so in this case he would say `"TextView.setText"` is not working, so i assume it is working and OP can see a "check mark"

Comment: yes i can see check box, but in green color

Comment: and did you try to set any fixed color like `Color.RED` ?

Comment: yes , issue us due to tick sign . i think so Samsung not support tick sign

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya you are right its due to special character

Comment: @user3269770 REad this http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2700-27BF

Answer (score 1):

u can set color for a textview using below ways

```
setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFF"));



    setTextColor(Color.RED)



    getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this problem arise from Special Character Symbol **`✔`**

Please read  **[Unicode](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2700-27BF)**

```
  setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
number.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView.setTextColor() does not accept 0xRRGGBB values. Instead, it accepts 0xAARRGGBB.

Thus, instead of 0xFF0000, try to set it to 0xFFFF0000

Answer (score 0):

I have solve problem after some research .some android device not support uni-codes.
so use

```
number.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u221A"));
```

instead of

```
number.setText("✔");
```